# NoReverseMatch, but it exist and was found

Tags: django, regex, django-views, django-urls

urls.py

```
url(r'^hr/checktask/(?P<pk>\d+[-]\w)/$', core_views.CheckTask, name='checktask_hr'),
url(r'^admin/checktask/(?P<pk>\d+[-]\w)/$', core_views.CheckTask, name='checktask_admin'),
url(r'^finance/checktask/(?P<pk>\d+[-]\w)/$', core_views.CheckTask, name='checktask_finance'),
url(r'^manager/checktask/(?P<pk>\d+[-]\w)/$', core_views.CheckTask, name='checktask_manager'),
```

Essentially, I have 4 separate urls, but they all call the same function. Each has a different name.

In my code, depending on my url, I will call one of those patterns

```
pk = 42387790148475610;
callingView = request.META.get('PATH_INFO').split("/")[1]
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checktask_' + callingView, kwargs={'pk': pk}))
```

But somehow, I get a NoReverseMatch error, despite it actually pointing to the right url pattern (hr in this case)

```
Reverse for 'checktask_hr' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '42387790148475610'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hr/checktask/(?P<pk>\\d+[-]\\w)/$']
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show all possible pattern example values? with `-`, `\w`. Or only continuous sequence of numbers is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pk` argument does not match the pattern for `pk` in the URL. Your pattern assumes that there is a dash (`-`) somewhere in the pk, but there is none in the value you are providing.

Comment: This is the most relevant answer to me. The source of my error is indeed due to the dash (```-```), but the underlying issue was that I was calling the wrong url pattern (this code was supposed to call another pattern that does NOT have the dash(```-```) in the regex pattern.). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
url(r'^hr/checktask/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',core_views.CheckTask, name='checktask_hr'),
....
```

Read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#id4